# Transporting LINQ query response from C# to JavaScript as dictionary

Tags: javascript, c#, linq, vue.js, parsing

I'm creating a website page using Vue and running up against a data-parsing problem because of the C#-JS crossover.

One of the C# backend files receives job data from the database:

```
IEnumerable<JobClasses> jobs = await dbContext.JobClasses.Where(x => x.CaseId == caseID).ToListAsync();
```

which is parsed into a corresponding object:

```
public JobClasses 
{
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public string PayrollName { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Some of these fields, in turn, will be extracted into a bigger class:

```
public Company
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Data Data { get; set; }
    public object[] JobClass { get; set; }
}
```

I need the `JobClass` in `Company` to hold multiple `ClassName`-`PayrollName` pairs so that I can later display them on my `Company`'s details page. Since each `Company` has many `JobClasses`, I'm not sure what object to use.

I considered using a `JobDetail` array, where `JobDetail` holds `ClassName` and `PayrollName`, something like this:

```
JobDetail[] jobsDetails = jobs.Select(x => x.ClassName, x.PayrollName);
```

but I can't find a way to make it work despite much googling and syntax-fiddling.

I also tried

```
var jobArray = from j in jobs select new { j.ClassName, j.PayrollName };
```

which gave errors later on because IEnumerable doesn't exist in JavaScript.

My question is: what's the ideal way to receive the data pairs from a LINQ query so that they can be passed smoothly through C# and into JavaScript without any extra parsing later on?

Comment: Can you add some test cases?

Comment: @aloisdgmovingtocodidact.com What sort of test cases? As in, examples of data?

Comment: Example of input/output mostly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_case

Comment: How are you serialising this to pass to JavaScript? Because *yes* IEnumerable doesn't exist but you'd be passing in *something* that's equivalent in data. Presumably a materialised collection. Then it's just a matter of how the serialisation is done - I'd expect an IEnumerable to be turned to a List/array which will then be turned into something JS will recognise as an array.

Comment: @VLAZ That's sort of my point... I'm not sure what sort of data to be passing through. I'm trying to find out if it's necessary to serialise again when the data gets to the JS, or if there's a way to do it once in the C#, in a generic-enough way to pass safely through JS

Comment: Also, my C#/LINQ is a bit bad but doesn't `jobs.Select(x => x.ClassName, x.PayrollName);` *not* select these two as a single value? It seems you need to produce a Pair (there was a built-in in C#, right?) or a Tuple (most definitely exists).

Comment: Course Tuple exists, but does it also exist in JS???

Comment: @Still_learning no...but you can just use an array with a fixed number of elements. Or an object with fixed properties as a "named tuple". I'd expect a serialisation library to handle these automatically.

Comment: So basically there's no way to only parse the data once in C# in a format that's compatible with JS as well?

Comment: I think you're getting caught up in the weeds here... The data will be sent in the structure you have it in C#, to JavaScript. You can then manipulate it however you want to in JavaScript. You don't get errors because `IEnumerable` doesn't exist in JavaScript; C# doesn't know squat about JavaScript.  C# will happily convert an `IEnumerable` to array syntax in JSON though. Do you just want to flatten your object model?

Answer (score 1):

Not enough rep to comment so I will try answering.
I adjusted your classes slightly. There were no class keywords. I would also suggest using consistent singular for class names as you did for *Company*. For consistency I also removed the class-suffix from JobsClass

So you have your Job class...

```
public class Job 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PayrollName { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

... and your Company class:

```
public class Company
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public object Data { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    }
```

The data you are pulling from your db with that statement...

```
IEnumerable<JobClasses> jobs = await dbContext.Jobs.Where(x => x.ID == jobID).ToListAsync();
```

... should result in objects like this (created from scratch here):

```
        List<Job> jobs = new List<Job>
        {
            new Job
            {
                Name = "Foo",
                PayrollName = "PrFoo",
                ID = 1
            },
            new Job
            {
                Name = "Bar",
                PayrollName = "PrBar",
                ID = 2
            },
        };
```

Now if you also have a company object you can simply assign your list of jobs to it:

```
Company company = new Company
            {
                Name = "Acme Inc",
                JobClasses = jobs
            };
```

When passing down the company object from C# to JS by e.g. ...

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(company);
```

... you end up with this JSON object:

```
{
   "Name":"Acme Inc",
   "Title":null,
   "Data":null,
   "Jobs":[
      {
         "Name":"Foo",
         "PayrollName":"PrFoo",
         "ID":1
      },
      {
         "Name":"Bar",
         "PayrollName":"PrBar",
         "ID":2
      }
   ]
}
```

So you have your company object and an array of jobs you can iterate over.
Probably this helps and I hope you do not mind me fiddling with your code.